# fittext - keep text in one line and not wrap into two lines

Tags: javascript, fittextjs

I use fittext.js and I try to make a h1 fit the whole width of the containing div in one line.

But the text makes two lines. 2014 of the text 17., 18. og 19. juli 2014 is on line two.
If I put nowrap on the h1, the text is in one line, but wider than 100%.

How to force the text to stay in one line?

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net demo of the issue would help

Comment: Of course, it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vd67h/
But the weird thing is that i jsfiddle it works.

Comment: Strange. Do you have it somewhere online where the issue happens?

Comment: http://www.vorbasse-marked.dk/web2014/

Comment: Put &nbsp;'s when u can

Comment: The problem is the plugin incorrectly judges the size and assigns incorrect font size. Trying to figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin incorrectly calculates fontsize with default compression ratio. Fortunately you can pass your own to correct the issue. Try this:

```
jQuery("#fittext").fitText(1.2);
```

Comment: Yes, that work, but I didn't think that was the right solution. But I'll go for that.

Comment: Perhaps font-family affects it or other factors. Plugin anticipated this otherwise it wouldn't provide the compression parameter.